# Disposable windows installation

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-registry

I find every few years I re-install windows on my PC for one reason or another eg. I install something which updates the registry and by the time I discover an issue it is too late to roll back.
I can fiddle with fixes but usually after some years it is cleaner to wipe it all and start up again.

For this reason I always partition my disk into 2, C: for Windows and D: for all my own stuff.
But when I re-install, as I've lost the original registry I also need to re-install all my games etc as well (and then pop the save games back from backup).

So it occurred to me, why not install windows on both drives, the D: windows would be passive, except when I install a game - then I boot up on D:, install the game, then reboot on C: again. For windows-related stuff I install on C: and if there is a deep late issue I re-install. Games rarely produce a windows related problem so I would rarely need to re-install on D:.

Now the question is, if you boot on D: and install, then boot on C:, would the game look in the D: windows' registry? Would it work?

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not understand a concurrent windows installation. So the registry hive is located at %WINDIR%, which when booting from C:\ is located at C, and D:\ when booted from D.

That being said, I too have struggled with the same issue as you, and found a pretty good way to counteract it.

If you use Steam and install games through it once to the steam folder, on a new windows install, you only need to install Steam to get your games back.

For applications, I use portable versions of the app. They don't require installation and its settings travel with the program. Just make sure both are located on your D drive, and the only thing you have to do after a reinstall is customize windows to your likings. These can be done by registry exports after you done them, and launching that reg file.

The beauty of this setup is that the programs will still work after you upgrade to a new windows install, and only the customization part may need tweaking. The downside is that a portable program can't update itself usually and requires updating it manually by downloading a new version of that portable program.

If there are a few programs you really want to keep updated, see if they come through a Ninite or PatchMyPC installer. That way, just one exe file installs all your programs.

Comment: This is a lovely answer to an awful question - but wouldn't the 'real fix' be to either a) not bugger it up in the first place, or b) have backups?  ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think so. At least, not the backup part. Its about the hastle of having to setup your windows after a reinstall, and making it as painless as possible. I know the techniques as slipstreaming etc, but they only work for one windows install and stop working the moment you want to upgrade to a new install. So I found it works best if most programs are portable or can be installed through one install.

Comment: You're probably right. I have to admit to a Mac-bias on this; so it's something I've only ever had to contend with on Windows, with its monolithic registry.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer, LPChip - very kind of you and great advice!! Thanks.

Comment: BTW Tetsujin I find lightly given insults very annoying these days. It's not an awful question at all. The idea that apps/games can be independent from Windows' own internal workings is obvious and sensible. MS allow - no, encourage, expect, design for - 3rd parties to integrate with the OS and then have no end of trouble trying to get them out again (eg root kit viruses that take over low level disk reading functions so that even Windows does not know they are there). Why not have an OS citadel and then only allow layer integrations on top of that?

Comment: Even the presumption that I want Windows all over my C: drive is OS-centric. The OS is just an engine and should be tucked under the bonnet, ie. in C:\Windows, end of story. Similarly user account separation is a separate issue from OS engine workings and there should be different, non-integrated solutions for that. I don't mind if you can't see my vision on this and I may even be way off base but there is never a need to condescendingly call a question 'awful'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In a dual-boot setup like you are describing, Windows will use its respective registry and program files depending on which OS you are booting from. This all happens during boot up so it would be very difficult to achieve this. You can make the reinstall process faster by creating and sys prepping a Windows image that you can deploy whenever you need to reload. An article for doing the process is below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation

You would basically install a fresh copy of Windows. Enter into audit mode and install all of your apps and make the customizations that you want and then run the sysprep command. It will then remove all of the machine specific data and drivers so that it can be deployed on another workstation. You would then extract that image using the command line on the Windows PE disk and capture the image to a flash drive.

If you need to reinstall Windows, boot to your Windows PE disk, create your partitions, and then deploy your image. Once it restarts you will be presented with the computer setup and once that finishes you will have all of your apps.

This is a little hands on and will likely require a little more research outside of the article above and once the work is done reinstalling is easy.

Josh

Comment: How well does this work if windows releases a new version and you want to upgrade to that new install? Aren't you required to sysprep that new version again? Also, can you copy the required information from that link into your answer in case that link becomes invalid in the future?

Comment: If it's just an install that will be reused on the same exact hardware, I wouldn't even bother with sysprep. IMO it's too much learning overhead for someone that just wants a reverted copy of their own machine. Just backup data separately and then capture an image of the main drive.

Comment: @LPChip Yes you would need to do this for every new version of Windows. I recently tried to sysprep a Windows 10 upgrade from 8 and it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @BrianC  It is a lot of overhead for a simple problem. But I have done this in the past and it has saved me time. Other than a Windows image, you could take a block-level backup of your disk every few weeks and roll back if you run into any issues.

Comment: Interesting - I must think about this a little more. Thank you.